# Función mb_strlen en PHP 7.2

Tags: php, apache2

Luego de actualizar la versión de PHP, he tenido errores fatales con la función mb_strlen. El error ha sido:

> Call to undefined function mb_strlen()

Luego de leer un poco, he desubierto que debe instalarse de manera intependiente, ya que no forma parte del lo que la versión considera. En múltiples artículos de internet hay versiones contrapuestas entre que la versión está obsoleta y/o que debe forzarse su instalación, sin embargo la documentación oficial no la menciona como tal, ni tampoco con la advertencia del "deprecated" (https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration72.deprecated.php).

1. Que alternativa a mb_strlen existe para la comprobación de palabras en español? (eñe, vocales con tílde, etc.)
2. La clásica función strlen ha incluido compromaciones multibyte de mb_strlen?
3. Existe alguna recomendación por la cual NO usar mb_strlen?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial la función `mb_strlen()` dejó de ser una función para convertirse en parte una extensión ([mbstring](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)), por lo que de querer usarla se ha de instalar independientemente, puesto ya no se incluye como una función que forme parte de su núcleo.

Si lo pensamos detenidamente, esto tiene bastante sentido, ya que se trata de una funcionalidad bastante grande que atesora [múltiples funciones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) relacionadas entre sí.

Una vez detallado esto para entrar en contexto, trataré de responder la preguntas que se han lanzando:

**1. ¿Qué alternativa a mb_strlen existe para la comprobación de palabras en español? (eñe, vocales con tílde, etc.)**

Entiendo que el objetivo del uso de esta función es el de obtener el número de caracteres "reales" de un `string`. Esto normalmente coincide con el número de **bytes** que ocupa, dado que **PHP** asume que un caracter es un **byte** con el que puede representar hasta 128 caracteres (0-127) y dejando el último **bit** para asegurar la integridad de los datos ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). ¿Qué ocurre cuando usamos un caracter que escapa a este limitado listado?

```
$string = 'Camión';

$letras = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
$letras2 = strlen($string);

echo $string . ': ' . $letras;
echo '<br>';
echo $string . ': ' . $letras2;
```

Esto nos devolvería:

> Camión: 6
>   Camión: 7

Aquí se puede apreciar la diferencia entre ambas funciones y también que para representar el caracter **ó** internamente se ha necesitado del uso de un **byte** adicional.

¿Qué podemos hacer para conseguir que `strlen` arroje el mismo resultado que `mb_strlen`? Una solución que se me ocurre es la de decodificar nuestro `string` **UTF-8** para que se codifique con [ISO 8859-1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), que es lo que ocurre cuando tratamos de usar caracteres que se salen de esta lista de 128. Esta norma contempla el uso de estos caracteres otorgándoles un valor representativo para que ocupen un **byte**.

> `utf8_decode` — Convierte una cadena con los caracteres codificados
>   ISO-8859-1 con UTF-8 a un sencillo byte ISO-8859-1

El mismo ejemplo de antes tratado con `utf8_decode`:

```
$string = 'Camión';

$letras = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
$letras2 = strlen(utf8_decode($string));

echo $string . ': ' . $letras;
echo '<br>';
echo utf8_decode($string) . ': ' . $letras2;
```

Esto nos devolvería:

> Camión: 6
>   Cami�n: 6

Otra posible alternativa seria usar la función `iconv_strlen()`

> A diferencia de `strlen()`, `iconv_strlen()` cuenta el número de veces que
>   aparece cierta secuencia de bytes str de acuerdo a la codificación de
>   caracteres especificada, resultado que no es necesariamente igual a la
>   longitud del string en bytes.

```
$string = 'Camión';

$letras = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
$letras2 = iconv_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');

echo $string . ': ' . $letras;
echo '<br>';
echo $string . ': ' . $letras2;
```

Que nos devuelve:

> Camión: 6
>   Camión: 6

**2. ¿La clásica función strlen ha incluido comprobaciones multibyte de mb_strlen?**

No, hasta donde he podido investigar no. Tampoco tendría sentido ya que esta funcionalidad se encuentra recogida en la extensión mencionada al inicio de la respuesta.

**3. ¿Existe alguna recomendación por la cual NO usar mb_strlen?**

No, tampoco tendría sentido que una actualización del lenguaje se convirtiera en una mala práctica.